# Fabric.js / Text Edit on mobile

Tags: fabricjs

I'm trying to use TUI Image Editor (https://github.com/nhn/tui.image-editor) in my Cordova app on Android.

It is based on Fabric.js and overall working reasonably, however I have major problems with the text annotation: If the edited text is in the lower part of the screen, the Android softkeyboard is covering the text input and doesn't scroll it into view. This also happens when I run the page in the normal Android Chrome browser.

Are there any recipes or examples how to get that working with Fabric.js?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I just avoided using the `IText` and `Textbox` objects. I just used the html input field and object with type `Text` in fabric.js without editing inside canvas, and editing inside input and changing text object to input value. Because if you will use the `IText` and `Textbox` objects, you will face problems with editing text on small texts, or text objects with a small scale, where editing inside canvas will be difficult and annoying.

If you still want to scroll to text object I can't give you a full solution. But I think you can use canvas [events](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/blob/master/dist/fabric.js#L27478) for text

```js
canvas.on('text:editing:entered', (textObject) => {
  // calculate canvas offset and textObject offset and scroll to this position
})
```

Comment: Thanks. Trouble is my current solution is based on tui.image editor which is a wrapper around Fabric. Will see if it's feasible to integrate this and if the event works when using TUI image editor.